# Good of you to see me

Tags: vocabulary

> “Good **of** you to see me.” (The Silkworm, by Robert Galbraith)

When I saw the sentence, I guessed that somewhere in dictionaries might be written that ‘*of*’ denotes ‘*in respect that*’; ‘*in respect to*’; ‘*considering*.’ Because I thought that the sentence would mean that ‘I think it’s good in respect that you've come to see me.’ This can be possible, I thought, considering this: *“of: used to give your opinion of somebody's behaviour; It was kind of you to offer. ([OALD, of #12](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/of))*” But RHD might not nod approval. For it says ‘of’ denotes ‘doer’ ([RHD, of #14](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/of?s=t)), not ‘in respect of’ (RHD, of #15). Is there no room at all to read as I first mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opinion of behavior is right.

I thank you for seeing me. You were under no obligation to see me, yet you are inviting me in that we may speak together about something.